# Translating All Numerical Words In A Sentence To Numbers

Tags: python, math, translation

I am attempting to make a calculator in python which can take a math problem presented in words and solve it (example - - input: sixteen plus twenty seven . . . . output: 16 + 27). Right now I am just working on translating words to numbers. I am using the w2n library. I have attempted to make a program that counts the words in a sentence, and loops a translation process for that amount of words. The translation process works like this: if that word is a number then translate it, if it isn't then leave it be. My problem is that when I `split()` my string, it turns into a list and the w2n library can not translate lists. I don't know how to solve this problem.

```
from word2number import w2n

test_str = "What is sixteen plus twenty seven"  # creating a testable string

x = test_str.split()  # splitting the test string so I can count the words

num1 = 0  # these variables will isolate each word
num2 = 1

y = 1

while y <= len(x):  # while y is less than the number of words in the string, this will repeat
  try:
    res = w2n.word_to_num(str(x[num1:num2]))  # translate the isolated word
    print("The string after performing replace : " + str(res))  # print the translation
    num1 = num1 + 1  # isolate the next word
    num2 = num2 + 1
    y = y + 1  #  when y = the number of words in the sentence, the loop will stop

  except ValueError:
    print(str(x[num1:num2]))
    num1 = num1 + 1
    num2 = num2 + 1
    y = y + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

To reassemble a number of the resulting words into a string to hand to `w2n`, for example in your split test string:

```py
>>> words = 'What is sixteen plus twenty seven'.split()
>>> words
['What', 'is', 'sixteen', 'plus', 'twenty', 'seven']
```

you can use [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) as follows:

```py
>>> ' '.join(words[4:6])
'twenty seven'
```

Your review of the list of words would be better handled as `for` loop:

```py
for y, word in enumerate(x):  
  try:
    res = w2n.word_to_num(word)  # translate the single word
    print("The string after performing replace : " + str(res))  # print the translation

  except ValueError:
    print(word)
```

which leaves you with the issue of translating multi-word numbers. However in the case of a successful one-word translation you could start building up a multi-word string to aslo try translation on.